# O qubit pode ser representado em booleano?

Tags: booleano, q#, programacao-quantica

Um bit pode ter apenas dois estados: verdadeiro e falso. Na computação quântica, foi introduzido o [qubit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit), ou bit quântico, no qual pode assumir **verdadeiro e falso simultaneamente**. Como isso é representado em forma booleana?

Ou melhor, é possível representar um valor booleano com programação quântica?

```
operation boolParaQubit (q : bool) (Qubit) {
    body {
        let valorBooleano = q;
        using (registrador = Qubit[1]) {
             X(registrador(valorBooleano));
             return M(registrador[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Ao chamar este procedimento, a saída é: `boolParaQubit(true) -> One`. Como ficaria se este `Qubit` não assumisse `Zero` ou `One`?

Comment: O qubit é uma informação booleana em sobreposição. E se você tentar aferir o seu valor, a função de onda da sobreposição entrará em colapso e apenas um valor será exibido. É mais física do que computação

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Clássico problema de querer determinar algo não determinístico da física quântica :D Só não faço ideia de como isso se reflete nessa linguagem Q#.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado isso me lembrou o paradoxo do Gato de Schrodinger.

Comment: Minha resposta explica isso =) E, sim, gatos para qubits

Comment: Qual resposta??

Comment: @CypherPotato a que está sendo escrita no meu computador. Precisei sair agora, mas em breve devo dar seguimento

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, se eu me enganei na notação bra-ket, me corrige lá na resposta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enquanto muitas vezes se usam elétrons ou fótons para se representar qubits, prefiro usar outra partícula fundamental da natureza. O gato.

Tomemos, então, um sistema de 3 qubits de gatos. Cada gato, para poder funcionar corretamente como qubit, precisa estar isolado do mundo. Se ele estiver de algum modo perceptível pelo mundo, toda troca de informação quântica (através de bósons) fará com que a função de onda do gato entre em colapso e ele deixará de se comportar como qubit para se comportar como bit. Então, precisamos pô-lo dentro de uma caixa eletromagneticamente opaca.

Agora, como será que eu faço a leitura do 1 ou 0 do qubit? Bem, precisamos ter dois estados distintos do gato. Com elétrons, esse medida pode ser a direção do *spin*. Mas gatos tem um spin muito difícil de ser medido, então precisamos de outro estado.

**Vivo** e **morto**, entretanto, é mais fácil de medir. Mas, como fazer isso? Colocando um pouco de urânio enriquecido, um contador Geiger e um frasco com cianureto; se o contador Geiger perceber a emissão radioativa dessa fonte de urânio, ele vai acionar um sistema que liberará o cianureto e o gato irá morrer imediatamente. Iremos colocar urânio o suficiente para, dado o intervalo de uma hora, a possibilidade de haver um decaimento radioativo ser de 50%. Logo, a cada hora, o nosso gato terá a mesma possibilidade de estar morto ou de estar vivo.

Segundo a interpretação de [Copenhagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_interpretation), isso significa que, para o mundo externo, o qubit do nosso gato estará em uma sobreposição de estados de **vivo** e **morto** ao mesmo tempo. Na interpretação da [onda piloto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_wave_theory) (defendida por de Broglie), entretanto, é impossível determinar externamente se o gato está vivo ou morto, mas ele estará, deterministicamente, através de alguma variável escondida, apenas vivo ou apenas morto.

> A teoria da onda piloto supostamente já foi falseada, mas não tenho a referência. Entretanto, diversos experimentos que demonstram a inexistência de variáveis escondidas foram realizados, e também tem um [experimento realizado](https://www.iflscience.com/physics/quantum-experiment-sees-two-versions-of-reality-existing-at-the-same-time/) que só faz sentido na interpretação de Copenhagen.

---

Então, vamos criar nosso algoritmo de geração de números aleatórios usando 3 qubits de gatos vivos. Iremos levar em consideração `1` como sendo o gato **morto** e `0` como sendo o gato **vivo**. Ao medir exatamente uma hora após o início do algoritmo, cada gato terá 50% de chance de estar morto.

Inicialmente estamos no seguinte estado:

```
q0           ; q1          ; q2
1|0> + 0|1>  ; 1|0> + 0|1> ; 1|0> + 0|1>
```

Para, após uma hora, estar no seguinte estado:

```
q0                           ; q1                          ; q2
sqrt(2)/2|0> + sqrt(2)/2|1>  ; sqrt(2)/2|0> + sqrt(2)/2|1> ; sqrt(2)/2|0> + sqrt(2)/2|1>
```

E, após outra hora, estaria no seguinte estado:

```
q0                     ; q1                    ; q2
1/2|0> + sqrt(3)/2|1>  ; 1/2|0> + sqrt(3)/2|1> ; 1/2|0> + sqrt(3)/2|1>
```

---

Isso que acabamos de montar foi um algoritmo quântico de geração de números aleatórios. Quando, por acaso, um sistema clássico for aferir o estado do sistema, a função entrará em colapso e ele estará em apenas um estado determinístico. Por exemplo, se depois de 1 passo de processamento quântico, pegarmos os 3 qubits, poderíamos pegar o número `010` com a mesma probabilidade de encontrar `001` ou `000`. Porém, após 2 passos de processamento quântico, a chance de encontrar `001` é bem menor do que `111`.

Cada "passo" quântico normalmente recebe outro nome: porta quântica (no mesmo sentido de portas de circuitos lógicos, como a porta AND ou a porta OR). A função de uma porta quântica, assim como a porta lógica tradicional, é pegar vários inputs e retornar outputs que dependem dessas entradas. A diferença entre uma porta clássica e da quântica é que a clássica fará um processamento determinístico, enquanto a porta quântica pegará inputs em sobreposição (lembrando que `1|0> + 0|1>` é uma sobreposição válida, em que só é possível observar `0` ao medir o valor do qubit) e retornará outputs também em sobreposição.

A nossa porta quântica, nesse caso da geração de números aleatórios, foi o passar do tempo. Não que isso seja muito útil, mas é o que pude fazer usando gatos, urânio e cianureto. No caso de sistemas quânticos em que você precisa resgatar essa informação e usar em outro cálculo (seja quântico seja clássico), essas portas normalmente envolvem coisas que interagem com fótons/elétrons.

---

> O qubit pode ser representado em booleano?

Segundo a interpretação de Copenhagen, o que conhecemos como um booleano é um qubit que está em constante colapso para o estado `1>` ou `0>`. Quando conseguimos parar de observar essa variável e a colocamos em um ambiente estocástico quântico, ela passa a assumir os múltiplos valores da sobreposição até ser novamente observado.

Então, um booleano é um caso específico de um qubit. E um qubit é uma sobreposição de, necessariamente, booleano.

---

Você pode ver mais de estados quânticos/computação quântica nos vídeos a seguir:

- [The Quantum Experiment that Broke Reality - PBS Space Time](https://youtu.be/p-MNSLsjjdo)
- [Why Quantum Computing Requires Quantum Cryptography - PBS Space Time](https://youtu.be/pi7YwxxZQ5A)
- [The Quantum Internet - PBS Space Time](https://youtu.be/_N-2Sx-FDQA)
- [Hacking at Quantum Speed with Shor's Algorithm - PBS Infinite Series](https://youtu.be/wUwZZaI5u0c)
- [The Mathematics of Quantum Computers - PBS Infinite Series](https://youtu.be/IrbJYsep45E)
- [How Quantum Computers Break Encryption | Shor's Algorithm Explained - minutephysics](https://youtu.be/lvTqbM5Dq4Q)
- [How to Teleport Schrödinger's Cat - minutephysics](https://youtu.be/DxQK1WDYI_k)
- [Hardy's Paradox | Quantum Double Double Slit Experiment - minutephysics](https://youtu.be/Ph3d-ByEA7Q)
- [The No Cloning Theorem - minutephysics](https://youtu.be/owPC60Ue0BE)
- [Bell's Theorem: The Quantum Venn Diagram Paradox - minutephysics](https://youtu.be/zcqZHYo7ONs)
- [Some light quantum mechanics (with minutephysics) - 3Blue1Brown](https://youtu.be/MzRCDLre1b4)
- [Quantum Cryptography in 6 Minutes - Up and Atom](https://youtu.be/uiiaAJ3c6dM)
- [Superposition of Quantum States - Up and Atom](https://youtu.be/VwWRX9IdblE)
- [How Does a Quantum Computer Work? - Veritasium](https://youtu.be/g_IaVepNDT4)
- [How To Make a Quantum Bit - Veritasium](https://youtu.be/zNzzGgr2mhk)
- [Single Photon Interference - Veritasium](https://youtu.be/GzbKb59my3U)

Comment: Ótima resposta para inaugurar a tag de computação quântica no site. Parabéns.

Comment: @CypherPotato, e ainda esqueci de botar alguma imagem do gato, hahah

Comment: Ah, sim, ainda devo melhorar a resposta pra deixar claro que o estado quântico booleano não tem nada a ver com os valores usados na lógica fuzzy...